# Import FBX using script

Tags: scripting, add-on

Edit: answered my own question! Moderators please delete if not appropriate to leave this here as it doesn't require an answer.

I'm a fool. But for anyone else who might have a similar question in the future ...

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath="F:/Blender/2019-04-09-S.fbx")
```

Source: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.ops.import_scene.html

---

Original question:

Can anyone help me to import an FBX file using a script in 2.80?

Based on other answers here, I've tried:

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx (filepath = 'F:\Blender\FBX\2019-04-09-S.fbx')
```

Comment: Could you put your answer as an actual answer and accept it as solution, so the question won't show up as unsolved? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer (to my own question), as requested.

For anyone else who might have a similar question in the future, don't forget to use forward slash '/' in filepaths ...

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath="F:/Blender/2019-04-09-S.fbx")
```

Source: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.ops.import_scene.html